# how can i get the cpu_id that my erlang vm is hosting on?

Tags: erlang

i have a question.

How can i know on which core (CPU) that the current Erlang VM hosts on?

Now i can only obtain the **pid** of current BEAM process by `os:get_pid`. And i can run a shell command in erlang code to get the core_id, but it is not graceful.

Like:

`Cmd = "ps -eo pid,psr,pcpu,pmem | egrep '^\\s*" ++ beam_pid() ++ "\\b'",

Res = os:cmd(Cmd).`

Is there any Erlang API provided?

Anybody can help me?

Thank you

Ruan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from comments to johlo's answer, you are running Erlang on Linux without SMP and with `taskset`.

The multi-platform code for handling CPU binding and affinity is in [erl_misc_utils.c](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/lib_src/common/erl_misc_utils.c). Erlang currently supports binding of scheduler threads on newer Linux, Windows, Solaris (and derived OSes with kstat) and FreeBSD. This is why `erlang:system_info(cpu_topology)` returns `undefined` on MacOS X. Yet, it works on your Linux distribution as reported in comments.

On Linux, `taskset` sets the CPU affinity of the subprocess. Yet, Erlang directly gets available CPUs from `/sys/devices/system`, and this ignores the current affinity. So **by using `taskset`, you are fooling Erlang** which, in SMP mode, might try to bind schedulers without success.

Besides, it seems the only way to know about the forced CPU affinity with `taskset` would be to get the CPU affinity. Which the **Erlang VM does not seem to expose through any API**. It seems that function `erts_get_available_cpu` which queries the OS for CPU affinity is [not even called](https://github.com/erlang/otp/search?q=erts_get_available_cpu&ref=cmdform).

I can see two solutions to your specific problem:

- since you are using `taskset`, you could pass some information (e.g. a configuration value) on the command line to tell your apps on which CPU they are running;
- alternatively, instead of `taskset`, you could use Erlang's ability to bind schedulers and provide
  your VM with a partial CPU topology of a single core. This trick is actually described in the [documentation of +sct option](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+sct). Then, using [`erlang:system_info(cpu_topology)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_cpu_topology) or [`erlang:system_info(scheduler_bindings)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_scheduler_bindings) will tell you which processor Erlang is currently running on.

This second solution is of course cleaner and more portable, although it will not work on some platforms as mentioned above. Please note that this *might* require to run Erlang in SMP mode, but a proper user defined topology with a single logical processor will make Erlang start a single scheduler. You can also pass [+S 1:1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+S) which is portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `erlang:system_info(cpu_topology).`, it returns info about which processors/cores are used. See [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_cpu_topology).

NOTE: on Mac OS X this doesn't seem to work, it just returns `undefined` for me.

Comment: but it lists all cpu information, how can i tell the right one?

Comment: @ruanhao it returns information about all cores *being used by the VM* to run the process schedulers (the VM can use more than one core). The VM can automatically distribute the workload over all cores listed by the cpu_topology.

Comment: SMP is disabled, and erlang is started by `taskset`, so it is bound to a certain core.